# Trying to find out my SATA speed

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have used `dmesg` and `lspci` and determined my hard drive. Looking to update to SSD. This is the terminal from `lspci`

`[    1.381803] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xbfa0 irq 14`

How can I determine the speed from this?

Answer (score 2):

Command:

```
dmesg | grep -i sata | grep 'link up'
```